# TypeError: can't pickle cv2.xfeatures2d_SIFT objects (occured during using joblib.Parallel)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I am trying to convert my code to parallel and used [joblib.Parallel](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.Parallel.html) for the purpose. I got the above error while feature calculating stage. Here is my code.

```html
from utils import FeatureGetter
#some code

Class model:
#initialize

def getDescriptors(image):
    descriptors = self.feature_getter.get_features(image)
    return descriptors

def train():
#some code
    self.feature_getter = FeatureGetter()
    descriptors_list = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(self.getDescriptors)(image) for image in self.X_train)
```

Complete Error log

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_parallel.py", line 375, in <module>
    bow.trainModel()
  File "test_parallel.py", line 144, in trainModel
    self.desc_list = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(self.getDescriptors)(image) for image in self.X_train)
  File "/home/vamsi.muthireddy/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/vamsi.muthireddy/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 620, in dispatch_one_batch
    tasks = BatchedCalls(itertools.islice(iterator, batch_size))
  File "/home/vamsi.muthireddy/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 127, in __init__
    self.items = list(iterator_slice)
  File "test_parallel.py", line 144, in <genexpr>
    self.desc_list = Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(self.getDescriptors)(image) for image in self.X_train)
  File "/home/vamsi.muthireddy/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 183, in delayed
    pickle.dumps(function)
TypeError: can't pickle cv2.xfeatures2d_SIFT objects
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?